# Suprema BioMini slim fingerprint web application

Tags: asp.net, biometrics

I bought a Suprema BioMini Fingerprint device. It has a SDK, but the documentation is not that good.

What I am trying to do is to create a web application using asp.net that interact with this fingerprint device, The SDK has a working web application that interact with the device.

I've used the Javascripts functions that comes with the sdk as the documentation says, but the following problem shows when I try to capture a fingerprint

(No session cookie is passed)

Have any one face that problem and managed to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you find a solution to use finger print device on web application ?

Comment: @SalarAfshar Yes I have found a solution, I have implemented an ActiveX Control to use the fingerprint device

Answer (score 0):

How about you enable cookies on your browser  and if that does not work you attempt to use another browser to see how it responds?

The other thing could be you are just running the HTML without hosting it on a webserver. If that is the case, check that you are using an appropriate webserver like IIS and confirm if it is running on your test / developer platform.

Answer (score 0):

salam mohammed

when you first log in to the server (from inside your code)
you will recieve a session id with the response.
store this session id, and every time you comunicate with the server, you must send this session id with the request stored in cookie, if you do not send the session id you will recieve this error: (No session cookie is passed).
Please see this link:

http://kb.supremainc.com/knowledge/doku.php?id=en:biostar_2_api_quickstart_guide

Comment: thank you,

my question is 2 years old, I have found another solution using ActiveX controls (it was very hard to do), but now it is working and the system in Production :D

Answer (score -1):

That's because you didn't set cookie in your java script codes (refer to page 251 in documentation).

Comment: can you please add the link to the documentation? And please don't add additional questions. Make an own question for this.

Comment: I supposed you have documentation, here is the link: https://www.4shared.com/office/WSdQG0VXei/BioMiniSDK_for_Windows_360_Ref.html

Comment: To understand easily, download sample project from here: https://www.4shared.com/rar/WAzqHq5Xei/JavaScript_Sample_Code.html

Comment: And sorry about questions, here is the link, please answer me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317330/suprema-biomini-javascript-codes